# Visual Studio 2019 is unable to start program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to learn C++ so I started following [microsoft's calculator tutorial](https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/cpp-calculator/create) here's my code so far

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Calculator Console App" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter an Operation from the following operations, a+b, a-b, a*b, a/b" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However when I press CTRL+F5 to start without debugging I get this error:
[Unable to start program 'C:\Users\Clark\source\repos\Calculator\Debug\Calculator.exe'. The system cannot find the file specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXdIq.png)

The #include in the #include "stdafx.h" line also has a red line under it, whenever I hover over it it says [cannot open source file "stdafx.h"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlVEu.png)

How can I fix this so that my code will actually run?

Comment: It should be `#include "pch.h"` in Visual Studio 2019. And in either case this file is one that is created in your project folder if you enabled precompiled headers. You may want to just disable precompiled headers anyways as it won't help you at all unless you have a project that includes a lot of external headers.

Comment: ***unable to start program*** You get that when the compile failed. If the compile failed you have no executable to run..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stdafx.h is a Precompiled header which is unnecesary unless you are facing a slow compilation time. Therefore, you can delete the following line: `#include "stdafx.h"` and continue your program.

Good luck in your jorney with C++!